# Comparison between contract type variable and address

Tags: solidity

How do you check if a contract mapping/variable is still to be initialized ?

comparing

```
contractTypeVariable != address(0)
```

gives a type error

> Operator != not compatible with types contract BasicToken and address

sample pseudocode:

```
Contract XYZ {

    mapping(uint256 => MyContract) private _contracts;
    ...
    function doStuff(uint256 i) ... {   
        require(_contracts[i] == address(0), "Contract already exists");
        ...

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If MyContract is an imported contract then you can get its address with
**address(_contracts[i])** and then compare it to the zero address.

```
Contract XYZ {

    mapping(uint256 => MyContract) private _contracts;
    ...
    function doStuff(uint256 i) ... {   
        require(address(_contracts[i]) == address(0), "Contract already exists");
        ...

    }
}
```

————-

If MyContract is a struct then:
You need to compare the values inside the struct and not the struct it self.

If the struct looks like this

```
struct MyContract {
  address addressOfContract;
  ..
}
```

and this `addressOfContract` is set when it is initialized and never change or get deleted.

Then you need to do this:

```
Contract XYZ {

    mapping(uint256 => MyContract) private _contracts;
    ...
    function doStuff(uint256 i) ... {   
        require(_contracts[i].addressOfContract == address(0), "Contract already exists");
        ...

    }
}
```

Comment: no, MyContract is a different contract,  imagine the "import .../MyContract.sol" at the beginning of the file and then _contracts[i] = new MyContract(constructor_params)

Comment: @Stormsson okay then try -> address(_contracts[i]) == address(0)

Comment: @Stormsson if it works then tell me to update my answer , otherwise i will delete it and edit your question.

Comment: yes, it works thank you! If you update the answer i'll flag it as solved.

Comment: @Stormsson Great I updated it , thanks

Comment: there's a mistake on the answer, just for future users, its not balance(_contracts[i]) ,it's a cast to an address, so : address(_contracts[i])

Comment: @Stormsson sorry working on the phone is not  a good idea :D. I updated the answer